# multiple objects scaling problem

Tags: mesh, objects

I want to scale multiple things at once but the "center of Scaling" should not be in the middle of all obyects i selected but in the middle of each seperat/induvidual obyects center. do you know what the shourtcut to this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, then scale as usual.

This is basically this option:

[image]